# In Vim, how can I automatically determine whether to use spaces or tabs for indentation?

Tags: vim, whitespace, indentation

Sometimes I edit others source code where the prevailing style is to use tabs. In this case, I want to keep the existing convention of using literal tabs.

For files I create myself, and files that use spaces as the prevailing indent style, I wish to use that instead.

How can I do this in vim?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use something like this in your `~/.vimrc` to adjust to use spaces/tabs as appropriate:

```
" By default, use spaced tabs.
set expandtab

" Display tabs as 4 spaces wide. When expandtab is set, use 4 spaces.
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

function TabsOrSpaces()
    " Determines whether to use spaces or tabs on the current buffer.
    if getfsize(bufname("%")) > 256000
        " File is very large, just use the default.
        return
    endif

    let numTabs=len(filter(getbufline(bufname("%"), 1, 250), 'v:val =~ "^\\t"'))
    let numSpaces=len(filter(getbufline(bufname("%"), 1, 250), 'v:val =~ "^ "'))

    if numTabs > numSpaces
        setlocal noexpandtab
    endif
endfunction

" Call the function after opening a buffer
autocmd BufReadPost * call TabsOrSpaces()
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a variety of plugins for that, for example (starting with my own):

- [My IndentConsistencyCop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690) examines the indent of the buffer and analyzes the
  used indent widths and methods. If there are conflicting ones or if bad
  combinations of tabs and spaces are found, it alerts you and offers help in
  locating the offenders - just like a friendly policeman: >
- [Indent Finder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=513) is a Python script and Vim plugin that scans
  any loaded buffer and configures the appropriate indent settings
- [yaifa.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3096) is a port to vimscript of the above
- [detectindent.vim](https://github.com/ciaranm/detectindent) by Ciaran
  McCreesh tries to auto-detect the indentation settings
- [GuessIndent](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4251) is based on detectindent.vim
- [indentdetect.vim](https://github.com/ervandew/vimfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/indentdetect.vim)
  by Eric Van Dewoestine performs a simple detection and can set defaults
  based on the filespec
- [matchindent.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4066) detects tabs, 2 and 4-space indents and
  adapts the indent settings accordingly
- [sleuth.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4375) by Tim Pope automatically adjusts 'shiftwidth'
  and 'tabstop' heuristically (via a simplistic sampling that does not check
  for bad or inconsistent indents) or by looking at other files of the same
  type
- [filestyle](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5065) highlights tabs when 'expandtab' is set,
  trailing spaces, and lines longer than 'textwidth', but doesn't actually
  check conformance to indent
- [ShowSpaces](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5148) highlights spaces inside indentation, per
  buffer / filetype.
- [Indent Detector](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5195) run when a file is opened or written, has
  warnings about mixed tab / space indent, and can adapt Vim's corresponding
  options automatically.

Comment: I saw another one, but know nothing about it. 12 stars and recently updated. https://github.com/timakro/vim-yadi

Comment: And one other mention: [`vim-polyglot`](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot), which contains syntax rules for lots of different languages, includes its own indentation detector.

Comment: So which one do you like the most? Always have a hard time choosing plugins... I'm a neovim user btw.

Answer (score 1):

One of the plugins posted earlier should be good for general use.

However, if you are working on a shared project, where people may be using *different* editors, then I recommending using a [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file to share the config across all editors.  For example:

```
[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
```

It is a fairly well known standard.  Some editors respect it out-of-the box, but others need a plugin.  Here is a plugin for Vim:

https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim

With this plugin installed, I find I am able to jump into someone else's project, and my editor will immediately respect their formatting conventions, even on new files.

And if I create a `.editorconfig` file, that makes it easier for other people opening my project.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this :) I finally need this after doing some (wrong) contributions on a neovim plugin. (all because of those literal tabs...)